# Regex to match string not working .*/text.*

Tags: c#, regex

i just want to match this string with regex: 
How can i do this?

```
/profil
```

i try do this in this way:

```
.*/profil.*
```

But my software dont match any results in text.

Comment: Do you want to include the forward slash?  \/profile should do it.

Comment: What software? Why did you use C# tag? `/profil` is equally good as  a string literal and a regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this

```
@"(\/profil)"
```

if all you need is to match `"/profil"` then there is no need for the `".*"`

Answer (score 0):

Remember the expressions are *greedy*.

The `.` matches any character, and `*` tells it that this `.` can go on forever. So this expression will eat up all of your input, leaving nothing for the `/profil` part.

It seems like you're trying to put a wildcard around `/profil`. This is not needed with regular expressions. You should just be able to use `/profil` as the full expression and match your string.

Comment: It is not true that *Remember the expressions are greedy.* The `*` is a greedy quantifier. Your explanation is wrong: *leaving nothing for the /profil part* would be true if the first `.*` was in the atomic group (`(?>.*)`).